# Find - Regex with path in input

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to find out a list of files matching in directory.

In Linux, the below find command is working if I mention it as "." but not with the exact full path "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content"

```
[root@ns content]# pwd
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content
[root@ns content]# 
[root@ns content]# find . -regextype sed -regex "./1510914114.stream\(_[0-9]\{1\}.mp4\|.mp4\)$"
./1510914114.stream_0.mp4
./1510914114.stream_1.mp4
./1510914114.stream.mp4
./1510914114.stream_2.mp4
[root@ns content]#
```

I have tried the below commands, not working in bash command line

```
[root@ns content]# find /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content -regextype sed -regex "./1510914114.stream\(_[0-9]\{1\}.mp4\|.mp4\)$"
[root@ns content]# 
[root@ns content]# 
[root@ns content]# find "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content" -regextype sed -regex "./1510914114.stream\(_[0-9]\{1\}.mp4\|.mp4\)$"
[root@ns content]# 
[root@ns content]# 
[root@ns content]# find "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content" -regextype sed -regex "1510914114.stream\(_[0-9]\{1\}.mp4\|.mp4\)$"
[root@ns content]#
```

Could someone help me to get the result with the actual path name in the input?

Comment: you have to change the path in your regex to absolute too : `find /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content -regextype sed -regex "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/1510914114.stream\(_[0-9]\{1\}.mp4\|.mp4\)$"`

Comment: Wow, Thanks. It helped. But I need to know only the filenames without full path in the result. Any suggestions?

[root@ns-344 content]# find "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content" -regextype sed -regex "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/1510914114.stream\(_[0-9]\{1\}.mp4\|.mp4\)$"
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/1510914114.stream_0.mp4
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/1510914114.stream_1.mp4
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/1510914114.stream.mp4
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/1510914114.stream_2.mp4

Comment: How about `cd /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content` followed by your initial `find .` ? You can do that inside a subshell if you don't want your current directory to change.

Comment: I pop out the filename using PHP array. I'm ok with that. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Don't be `root`.  You're welcome.

Comment: Specifying a single repetition of something is just useless.  If all the paths match the regex `\.mp4` why do you even need the first alternate, or a regex at all?

Comment: There are some more files like 1510914114.stream_1_12312312pdsfsd.mp4 in the same directory which I don't want